# Integral of a two dimensional function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A function is defined by
$$f(x,y) = \int_{x^2}^{xy} e^{t^2} \,dt$$
We are to decide the partial derivatives of the function.

I am quite unsure whether this is a trick question because we could do an approximation of the integrand with the Taylor series, but I can't see how that would simplify the work.

Could I just get a direction to as how I should approach this problem? I would very much not like to just get the solution.

Note that this is one of the easiest questions on the paper.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @caverac : To apply a rule like that isn't the same as understanding how the rule comes from things learned in first-year calculus. And you don't need anything nearly as strong as that rule, since the function being integrated does not depend on $x$ or $y. \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the fundamental theorem of calculus gives us
$$f(x,y) = \int_{x^2}^{xy} e^{t^2} \,dt = \int_{0}^{xy} e^{t^2} \,dt - \int_{0}^{x^2} e^{t^2} \,dt$$
$$\implies$$
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} (F(xy) - F(x^2)) =yF'(xy) - 2xF'(x^2) = ye^{x^2 y^2}-2xe^{x^4}$$

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = xe^{x^2y^2}$$

Thanks for the help, I knew this was supposed to be easy. Just looking at it from a different perspective!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: If we let $F(s) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{s}e^{t^2}\,dt$, then $f(x,y) = F(xy)-F(x^2)$.

Now, try using the chain rule to compute $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}\left[F(xy)-F(x^2)\right]$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}\left[F(xy)-F(x^2)\right]$. Remember that by construction, $F'(s) = e^{s^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
& f(x,y) = \int_{x^2}^{xy} e^{t^2} \,dt = \int_0^{xy} e^{t^2} \, dt - \int_0^{x^2} e^{t^2} \, dt. \\[10pt]
& \frac d {du} \int_0^u e^{t^2} \, dt = e^{u^2}. \\[10pt]
& \frac d {dx} \int_0^u e^{t^2}\,dt = \frac d {du} \int_0^u e^{t^2} \, dt \times \frac{du}{dx}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$f(x,y)=\int_{a(x,y)}^{b(x,y)} g(t) \, dt$$ Using the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial b(x,y)}{\partial x}\, g(b(x,y))-\frac{\partial a(x,y)}{\partial x}\, g(a(x,y))$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial b(x,y)}{\partial y}\, g(b(x,y))-\frac{\partial a(x,y)}{\partial y}\, g(a(x,y))$$

Just apply.